# how do I strip off everything after a certain string

Tags: python, strip

basically I want to turn something like this

```
FlorenceBuilding04_geometry_clean_001_Loc1_position
```

to

```
/root/world/geo/FlorenceBuilding04_model_geometry
```

and

```
FlorenceBuilding05_geometry1_clean_001_Loc1_position
```

to

```
/root/world/geo/FlorenceBuilding05_model_geometry
```

Code:

```
s = GetName()
if s.endswith( "_position" ):
    rootname = "/root/world/geo/"+s[ :- 18 ].rstrip("_")
    rootname =rootname.replace("geometry","model_geometry")
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: it doesnt always end with 18 characters nor a _ so I want to basically delete everything after the word "geometry"

Comment: oh, right. `.split('geometry')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And you could do this also:

```
>>> a = 'FlorenceBuilding04_geometry_clean_001_Loc1_position'
>>> path = '/root/world/geo/' + a.split('geometry')[0] + 'model_geometry'
>>> print(path)
/root/world/geo/FlorenceBuilding04_model_geometry
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't very specific about the criteria, but it seems like you want to keep the first part up to "_geometry" and discard everthing else. That is easily done with `index`:

```
>>> def convert(example):
...     print "/root/world/geo/%s_model_geometry" % example[:example.find("_geometry")]
... 
>>> convert("FlorenceBuilding04_geometry_clean_001_Loc1_position")
/root/world/geo/FlorenceBuilding04_model_geometry
>>> convert("FlorenceBuilding05_geometry1_clean_001_Loc1_position")
/root/world/geo/FlorenceBuilding05_model_geometry
```